# why not used graph id also need disk space

Tags: neo4j

our neo4j's graphid is nonsequence,in order to protect my data.

for example: 
first node id is 1000,
the second id is 1050,
the thrid is 2000

but we found not used graph id also need disk space.

what config we can use that we can make non-used-graph-id not need disk space?

if sequence,graph only need 35G disk space, but use nonsequence,need 73G space

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j node ID is nothing more than an offset into the Neo4j nodes file. Your clients should not see this ID *ever*, regardless of what you're trying to do. As Reed suggests, use a UUID and expose that to your client. https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid may help.

Answer (score 0):

How are you "protecting your data" using no sequential graph ids?

Why not use random letter+number combinations? For example, e4T, h98, 77y. They are short and store tens of thousands of records with just 3 digits.

Using uuid might also be an option.

Comment: I think the non used graph id may also allocate property's space,although no  property in non used graph id.